Semiclassical limit of spectral gap of Schrödinger operators with nonsmooth potential
Let $\Omega$ be a connected compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. It is well known that for a smooth potential $V:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ that has a unique nondegenerate minimum $V(0) = 0$, the operator $H = -h^2\Delta + V$ will have its spectral gap converge to that of a simpler operator $H = -h^2\Delta + \frac{1}{2} x^\intercal A x $ when $h \to +0$, where $A \succ 0$ is the Hessian of $V(x)$ at $x=0$. This is basically saying that the local behavior of $H$ can be approximated by replacing $V$ with its quadratic equivalent. See e.g. Theorem 11.3 of [HS]. (Actually the whole low-energy spectrum will converge too, though not uniformly.)
My question is, do we know any kind of similar results when $V$ is only continuous but not smooth?
Update (Oct 14). The domain of $V$ changed from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\Omega$ in order to avoid tricky behavior of $V$ at infinity.
[HS] Hislop, Peter D., and Israel Michael Sigal. Introduction to spectral theory: With applications to Schrödinger operators. Vol. 113. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Even in the smooth case, what do you do if it turns out that $A=0$?

@MichaelEngelhardt Thanks for pointing out. The result assumes that $A \succ 0$.

You will certainly need much stronger assumptions on $V$, or you could (for example) have $\sigma (H)=[0,\infty)$ and there's no spectral gap to discuss.

@ChristianRemling Can you give an example? afaik the spectrum of $V$ is discrete if its $d/2$-power is integrable by Weyl’a law.

@Lwins: $V$ only needs to go to zero fast enough, then the spectrum is purely ac on $[0,\infty)$.
